# How to make a Custom Progessbar with 2 SVGs? using a Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a custom progessbar that looks like this:

[image]

I want to combine it with a count down timer, so the progressbar starts completly filled and to the end of the timer there should only be the background.

I created these two .svg's

[image]
[image]

I'm wondering how I should create this progressbar.

Should I use a html canvas? I can draw the arrow with this code:

```
  const ctx = this.arrow.getContext('2d');
  const img = new Image(200, 200);
  img.src = "../../../assets/positive-arrow-empty.svg";
  img.onload = () => {
    console.log('loaded', img);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 200, );
  };
```

But I can't figure out how I can cut off the image and animate the whole process.

How could I do that or is there a better way then using a canvas?

Comment: Place one over the other (absolutely positioned, and both rendered) and animate the height of one, revealing the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others suggested, canvas looks unnecessary here. If anything, it'll make the whole thing perform worse, since you'll need to clear the whole canvas and re-draw both images on each frame. Here's a solution that uses [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path):

```js
const full = document.querySelector('.full')
full.style.clipPath = 'inset(0 0 0 0)'

let time = 5000
const frequency = 50
let clipPercentage = 0
const id = setInterval(() => {
  full.style.clipPath = `inset(${clipPercentage}% 0 0 0)`
  clipPercentage += 100 / (time / frequency)
  if ((time -= frequency) <= 0) {
    clearInterval(id)
  }
}, frequency)
```

```css
.full, .empty {
  position: absolute;
}
.full {
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<img class="full" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V4sE.png"></img>
<img class="empty" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJtCo.png"></img>
```

This example uses PNGs but SVGs should work the same way.

Comment: Thank I didn't knew about css clip. That works great!

Comment: Just so you know, your two images need to get redrawn entirely every frame too here, just like it would have been on a canvas.